# Is there a non recursive formula for mixed resistors?

Tags: resistors, resistance

In equivalent resistors in multiple parallel resistors, like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuMTE8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I need a formula for the equivalent resistance for the whole circuit, but in a way that, this formula can be generalized for more than 5 nets.

I've done this:

2E is the equivalent resistor for the last net, because they're in serie. Then, the next is in parallel: 2ED/(2E+D) and so on... but it looks really awful when finally get to the first net.

Every time this expression keeps growing and growing, I would like a simple formula for this:

[image]

By using some power of 2 instead of the R's, I get those simplifications:

[image]

But, nothing simple to make a generalization for further terms.
NOTE: \$Req(i)\$ represents a circuit with \$i\$ nets on it.

Comment: For questions that look very much like homework problems, it's appreciated if you at least show you've put some work into solving it yourself.

Comment: and using a solid colour background doesn't aid the readability of a circuit.

Comment: @DanLaks doesn't read like homework to me - it's obvious hkviktor knows the right formula and method - just not if there's a "better" or "tidier" way of doing it.

Comment: Maybe the maths SE might help you reduce your long-hand formula into a more compact version? The methods used wouldn't be specific to electronics.

Comment: My image had a white background, but here appears to have a green one, @JImDearden.

Comment: I think what you have does is totally correct, collect the terms to make it smaller...

Comment: You also need to specify the two nodes between which you want the resistance. Did you really intend to short out the left end of the circuit?

Comment: It looks like your edit has changed the question. My answer has pairs of equivalent resistances like you had originally - I'm not sure if this is what you intended.

Comment: Are you sure that your last equation is right ( I didn't go through all your working) But it VERY nearly all cancels out to being Req = 2C Which I am fairly sure is not correct..

Comment: So, all your R's are identical? Then you get indeed a ratio of Fibonacci numbers which converges to the golden ratio. Otherwise things get a bit more complicated.

Comment: I'm downvoting this for originally having a wrong diagram, basically with 0 equivalent resistance. Someone other than the OP "fixed" the question by removing the entry/exit nodes altogether. But that's not really a fix... unless you want people to guess *from the formula(s)* what network you're trying to solve. The info on whether the resistors are assumed all equal (or not) still hasn't been made explicit in the question either.

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with the golden ratio I think: -

[image]

or...

[image]

For N = 1,

x = \$\dfrac{13}{8}+\dfrac{-1^{2} \cdot 3!}{3!\cdot 1!\cdot 4^{5}}\$ =

x = \$\dfrac{13}{8}+\dfrac{3!}{3!\cdot 4^{5}}\$ = 1.6259765625

Anyway the link is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) and I can't vouch for it being perfect.

Comment: But that only works if all the resistors have the same value, I guess.

Comment: Oh, now I see that the OP has updated the question, and indeed, now all R's are the same ...

Comment: Maybe, It's certainly possible for me to make a math mistake. (I screwed up a pressure conversion making my first flow impedance and made it x10 too big..)

Comment: I suppose that by \$N\$ you mean the value of one resistor? What do you do when \$N\neq1\$?

Answer (score 0):

I get a series that looks like (Assuming equal R's)

1.) R(1+1/1)

2.) R(1+2/3)

3.) R(1+5/8)

4.) R(1+13/21)

5.) R(1+34/55)

I can write down the rest of the terms... but I'm not very good at finding a closed form solution.

Edit Re: ratio, So do a few sections and check me.  Given number N(i) = 1+a/b the next number is,

N(i+1) = 1+(a+b)/(2a+b)

and N(1) = 1+1/1.. (a=1, b=1)

That's still a recursive relation.

Comment: Actually, $$R_i=\frac{R_{i+1}}{2}$$, for each $$0\leq i\leq n$$

Comment: Hmm, I don't follow... the terms continue..89/144, 233/377, 610/987, 1597/2584.... if you calcutlate the ratio it's 0.61803...

Comment: Ah the golden ratio!! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio or... \$\dfrac{1}{x} = 1+x\$

Answer (score 0):

I'm becoming quite sure that it's not possible to give a non-recursive formula for this. Diverger's answer shows a way to represent the equivalent resistance as a continued fraction:

> $$R_{T_n} = R + \frac{\vdots}{\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{R+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R}+\frac{1}{R+\frac{1}{ \frac{1}{R} + \frac{1}{R} }}}}}$$

However, to make this a general function, that works for any \$n\$, without dots, we would need a [generalized continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction), like this:

> $$A_n = b_n A_{n-1} + a_n A_{n-2}, \qquad B_n = b_n B_{n-1} + a_n B_{n-2}$$

However, this uses recursion (\$A_n\$ is defined in terms of \$A_{n-1}\$ and \$A_{n-2}\$, and analogically the same with \$B_n\$), and you didn't want recursion.

Andy's answer using the golden ration [seems](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/135408/is-there-a-non-recursive-formula-for-mixed-resistors/139647?noredirect=1#comment282594_139647) to work only when R=1. Otherwise the formula doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are all incorrect since the answer is 0 Ω from inspection.  Note that A and B are *directly connected*.  All the resistors are just red herrings to see if you fall for doing all the math and then coming up with the wrong answer anyway.  Looks like it worked.

Comment: Heh, good point. But I actually think that's my mistake, I put the A and B nodes - and on the wrong place, apparently. Maybe this is indeed the intention of the question, or the resistance between the bottom left and the top right has to be calculated.

Answer (score -1):

If you label your resistors from right to left as \$r_1, r_2, ... , r_n\$ as in the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw2MEx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

then the equivalent resistance \$R_n\$ for \$n\$ resistors is

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
R_n & = & r_n + \frac{r_nR_{n-1}}{r_n+R_{n-1}} \\
& = & r_n (1 + \frac{R_{n-1}}{r_n+R_{n-1}})
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

but it doesn't seem very easy to solve this in terms of \$n\$ and the \$r_n\$ values. You could easily write a program/spreadsheet/etc to do these calculations, but you'd have to try some place a bit more math-heavy to find a closed-form answer.

Comment: How did you get that formula?
I mean, this formula is for the $n$ net of the circuit or for the equivalent resistor of a circuit with $n$ nets?

Comment: I took the right side of the circuit as one resistor \$R_{n-1}\$ and combined it with the new pair of resistors (in series and parallel, like you did in your question).

Comment: I didn't see the second half of your comment - \$R_n\$ is the resistance of the ladder with \$n\$ rungs. (ie: you calculated \$R_3\$ but with E, D, and C instead of \$r_1, r_2, r_3\$)

Comment: OP is looking for a non-recursive formula (see the title), but you define \$R_n\$ in terms of \$R_{n-1}\$.

Answer (score -1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffRP9S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Start Thévenin equation at left end. Every stage contain a series resistor and a resistor pull-down. The series resistor will be in series with the previous stage's thévenin equivalent resistor.

$$
R_{T0}=0\\
R_{T1} = (R_{T0}+R_{1}) || R_{2}\\
R_{T2} = (R_{T1}+R_{3}) || R_{4}\\
R_{T3} = (R_{T2}+R_{5}) || R_{6}\\
...\\
R_{Tn} = (R_{Tn-1}+R_{2n-1})||R_{2n}
$$

If all \$R\$s are equal. Then

$$
R_{Tn}=(R_{Tn-1}+R)||R
$$

Use Python or other languages to make a small app can calculate this, but it's a "recursive formula".

Let's think more. If your expand the equation above, it should be like a "[Continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)".

**Note:** Continued fraction doesn't mean "infinite", if your count of resistor is fixed, then the expression will be finite.

$$
R_{Tn} = \frac{\vdots}{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{ \frac{1}{R} + \frac{1}{R} }+R}+\frac{1}{R}}+R}+\frac{1}{R}} + R
$$

Per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression, Continued fraction is not a "closed-form expresson" but a "analytic expression".

Comment: OP asked for a non-recursive formula (see the title), but you're defining \$R_{T_n}\$ in terms of \$R_{T_{n-1}}\$. Yes the last one doesn't do that, but it has dots...

Comment: The last isn't infinite! The last is the most left of the circuit. If i write from bottom, the dots should be at the top!!!

Comment: True, but because of the dots, when you write it out, it's not a general function because it's different for different values of n.

Comment: Yes, so i think that's why it's not a "closed-form expression", just for discussion and sharing. +/-1 is nothing.

Comment: There's a difference between finite continued fractions (this one, for example) and infinite continued fractions. According to the closed-form wiki, especially "Unlike the broader analytic expressions, the closed-form expressions do not include infinite series or continued fractions", finite series of continued fractions are members of the set of closed-form expressions. But in any case, this is not really a *general* function.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by "Unlike the broader analytic expressions, the closed-form expressions do not include infinite series or continued fraction", continued faction have two class, infinite and finite ones, but it simply says "continued fraction", and the table below don't mention infinite/finite, i think i should find other references.

Comment: We're very close to the definition of closed-form expressions I have the idea. I can't find it so quickly, but probably [math.se] could help out.

Comment: Yes, so many docs try to find the closed form of continued fraction, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459938/closed-form-for-this-continued-fraction

Comment: That one seems to be about an infinite continued fraction again. I can't find it there. Let's ask it. Do you want to ask it or shall I?

Comment: Please, go ahead. My English is not so good.

Comment: [Is a finite continued fraction a closed form expression?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1033632/63495)

Comment: @CamilStaps: Good work. And please check the last equation i post, is it right? If it is, then the circuit can't fit into a "golden ratio" problem, because \$R \not= 1 \$, and it's finite.

Comment: You're opening a very interesting point against Andy's answer. I think you're right, but I'm not sure. I'm quite sure your equation is right though. By the way, have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Notations_for_continued_fractions) - it shows different ways of expressing the same formula as yours, without dots.

Comment: Right, some are very easy to remember. but some may need extra explanation. You know, in math, there always some **rule** to write something. I think we've gone into mathematics, but not EE, :).

Comment: The problem states that each $R_i$ is in a geometric progression, they are not equal

Comment: 1> The circuit shows all Rs are 100 ohms. 2> I only saw Req(i), but not R_i, if you mean Req(i), then it only present the "stage" equivalent resistance, not individual resistor.